# SQL Query success in xampp but error in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have query :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Count(*) as age15
        FROM users 
        WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) <=15) as Age,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age16
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) BETWEEN 16 AND 20) as Age1,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age21
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) BETWEEN 21 AND 25) as Age2,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age26
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) BETWEEN 26 AND 30) as Age3,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age31
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) BETWEEN 31 AND 35) as Age4,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age36
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) >=36) as Age5
```

I have tried this query in xampp phpmyadmin and success

I tried to implement in CodeIgniter and give error "The query you submitted is not valid.". Code :

```
public function get_count_age_user(){  
    $this->db->query(`SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT Count(*) as age15
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) <=15) as Age,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age16
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) BETWEEN 16 AND 20) as Age1,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age21
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) BETWEEN 21 AND 25) as Age2,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age26
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) BETWEEN 26 AND 30) as Age3,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age31
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) BETWEEN 31 AND 35) as Age4,
        (
        SELECT Count(*) as age36
            FROM users 
            WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(now(), users.date_of_birth)/365.25) >=36) as Age5`);

    foreach($query->row_array() as $row){ 
        $result = array(
            array('title' => "< 15 yearsold", 'total' => $row['age15']),
            array('title' => "16 - 20 yearsold", 'total' => $row['age16']),
            array('title' => "21 - 25 yearsold", 'total' => $row['age21']),
            array('title' => "26 - 30 yearsold", 'total' => $row['age26']),
            array('title' => "31 - 35 yearsold", 'total' => $row['age31']),
            array('title' => "> 36 yearsold", 'total' => $row['age36']),
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

am i missing something? i am very grateful if you know to implement to active record thank you

Comment: Probably the backticks instead of the single quotes at beginning and end of the query?

Comment: can you give me example to fix the query?

Comment: Use the same quotes you are using around title (for example) instead of the backticks you have now